# Android studio emulator can't connect to localhost 10.0.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

My android studio emulator can't connect to my localhost. I already tried 10.0.2.2 and 192.168.60.124, but both didn't work.

I thought that could be the proxy, but I already set it.

I really don't know what might be. Can you guys help me, please?

Error: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Have you try to disable windows firewall?

Comment: `My android studio emulator can't connect to my localhost` ???? The emulator will not try to connect. Probably you mean an app running on the emulator. Further that app will not try to connect to your pc but to a server running on your pc. You omitted relevant info.

Answer (score -1):

Check your localhost ip on your machine by opening cmd and typing ipconfig
and check that the I.P. is same

OR

Change your Open Network and Sharing connection to Home Network.

HOPE ONE OF IT WILL SOLVE YOUR PROBLEM

Comment: The localhost ip is correct. I tried again. How do I do this "Open Network and Sharing connection to Home Network." ?

Comment: Akshay, I tried to share the connection, but I got an error from windows :(

Comment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Go through this link -  https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-fix-ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED-on-Chrome

Comment: I tried to disable windows firewall, but I got an error too.